# Phonegap / iOS: is it possible to customize the recorder interface?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I was bale to create a fully working example with the Media.API
but what if I want to change the interface of the default recorder?

I'd like to be able to click & record avoiding an extra screen
is that possible? (at least on iOS)

I see I can edit some ong on the Capture.Bundle... but how to change position of the elements etc...